# mysqldump bash script throws error

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

Hi I'm trying to create a script that backs up some tables. The number of tables is quite large and i dont want to copy paste the command. Here is my script.

```
#! /bin/bash
#The following commands exports/dump tables
# Usage: sh export-script DBName username password
#
#
#
export TABLES="A B C D...Z"
#
mysqldump $1 --skip-add-drop-table --replace --no-create-info --user=$2 --password=$3  ${TABLES} > dump.YYYY-MM-DD.sql
```

However i getting the following error:

"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "Z

I'm new to scripting and amazingly i couldn't find a solution to this simple problem. SOS.

Comment: The script runs without problems when i copy/paste it on terminal.

Comment: if MS windows was involved in creating the script file, use `dos2unix mySqlDumperScript.sh`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I assume you replace `export TABLES="A B C D...Z"` with a list of tables that doesn't contain the ellipsis.  Sorry, had to ask because some expect `bash` to behave like other scripting environments that may expand `D...Z` to `D E F ... etc`, which it does not.

Try with double-quoting the `${TABLES}` argument, like so:

```
mysqldump $1 --skip-add-drop-table --replace --no-create-info --user=$2 --password=$3  "${TABLES}" > dump.YYYY-MM-DD.sql
```

This will pass in all the tables as a single argument.  If this doesn't work, I recommend looping:

```
for table in ${TABLES} ; do
    mysqldump $1 --skip-add-drop-table --replace --no-create-info --user=$2 --password=$3  ${table} > dump_${table}.YYYY-MM-DD.sql
done
```

Notice how this creates a separate `dump_` SQL file for each table.  If you require one file for all tables, use:

```
/bin/rm -f dump.YYYY-MM-DD.sql
for table in ${TABLES} ; do
    mysqldump $1 --skip-add-drop-table --replace --no-create-info --user=$2 --password=$3  ${table} >> dump.YYYY-MM-DD.sql
done
```

I just noticed that the comments suggest you run with `sh ...`.  Don't run with `sh`.  Run with `bash export-script DBName username password`, or simply run with `export-script DBName username password` and let the process shell choose which shell to run the script with via the `#!` line at the top.  In this case, it will run with `bash`.

Comment: I think there was a problem with the line endings. I should've mentioned in the question that i used windows to write this script. and yes, it should run with bash since the file starts with #!. Thanks for your help.